# Domain of a radicand with an odd index?

Tags: functions, roots

I don't understand the answer to this problem.

Q: Find the domain of the following function: $g(x) = (x - 1)^{1/3}$

A: Because the index is odd, the radicand, $x-1$, can be any real number.

I thought that if the integer in the root was negative, like any number less than $1$, that it was not in the domain. Why does the odd index, i.e. $3$rd root, change that?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{-1}$ isn't a real number but $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ is (indeed, it is $-1$).

Comment: Every real number has a unique cube root.  In fact, if the index $n$ is odd, every real number has a unique $n$th root.

Comment: Because $w^{even} = negative$ is impossible we can not have $\sqrt[even]{negative}$.  But $w^{odd}= negative$ **is** possible (if $w$ is negative).  So $\sqrt[odd]{negative}$ is possible.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about square roots, the value $\sqrt{-1}$ can’t be any real number. One way to see this is that if $x = \sqrt{-1}$ is a real number, then

- if $x = 0$, then $x^2 = 0$ and $0 \ne -1$;
- if $x > 0$, then $x^2$ is the product of two positive numbers, and therefore is positive, and can’t be -1; and
- if $x < 0$, then $x^2$ is the product of two negative numbers, and therefore is positive, and can’t be -1.

In other words, $\sqrt{-1}$ can’t be a real number because multiplying any real number by itself doesn’t give a negative number.

However, this isn’t true for cube roots. Take $\sqrt[3]{-8}$, for example. Notice that

$$-2 \times -2 \times -2 = (-2 \times -2) \times -2 = 4 \times -2 = -8,$$

so -2 is a cube root of -8. The fact that we multiplied an odd number of negative numbers together means that the result is negative.

More generally, even roots of negative numbers can’t be real numbers because multiplying an even number of numbers of the same sign never gives a negative number. However, odd roots of negative numbers do exist, because multiplying an odd number of negative numbers together gives back a negative number.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because $(negative)^{odd} = negative$ but $(negative)^{even} = positive$.

(And, of course, $0^{anything\ (except\ 0)} = 0$ and $(positive)^{anything} = positive$.)

Now the definition of $\sqrt[n]{x} = w$ means $w^n = x$.

If $n$ is even, then $w^n = negative$ is impossible so $\sqrt[n]{negative}$ can not exist.

But if $n$ is odd, then $w^n = negative$ is perfectly possible if $w$ is negative as well.  No problem at all.  $\sqrt[n]{negative}$ can certainly exist.

Furthermore we can conclude if $n$ is odd, that if $w > 0$ then $w^n > 0$ but if $0^n = 0$ and if $w < 0$ then $w^n < 0$.  So $\sqrt[n]{x}$ will be negative if and only if $x$ is negative.  And $\sqrt[n]{x}$ will be positive if and only if $x$ is positive.  An $\sqrt[n]{x}=0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

But only if $n$ is odd.

======

Consider $\sqrt[3]{-27}$.  That would mean there is a $w$ so that $w^3 = -27$.  Now $(-3)^3 = (-3)*(-3)*(-3) = 9*(-3) = -27$.  So $\sqrt[3]{-27} = -3$.

No problem!

Now consider $\sqrt[4]{-81}$.  That would mean there is a $w$ so that $w^4 = -81$.  Hmmm,  Well $3^4 = + 81$ and $(-3)^4 = (-3)*(-3)*(-3)*(-3)=9*9 = 81$ and neither of them are equal to *negative* $-81$.... Can it be something else?  If $w < 0$ then $w^2 > 0$ and $w^4 > 0$ so $w^4 \ne -81$ if $x < 0$.  And if $w=0$ then $w^4 = 0^4 =0\ne -81$.  And if $w > 0$ then $w^2 > 0$ and $w^4 > 0$ and so $w^4 \ne -81$.  So $w <0$ is impossible, and $w =0$ is impossible.  And $w> 0$ is impossible.  What other options are there?

None..... there are no other options so $w^4 =-81$ is impossible and $\sqrt[4]{-81}$ can not exist.